# Pass info from template to component via ngModel

Tags: angular, templates, binding, components

I am trying to pass some string data or more specifically URL from the HTML template to component on button click. This is what I am doing.

1. I have imported ONLY `FormsModule` in `app-module`.
2. Then in the component where I need to display all this i.e home component, I have not imported anything.
3. This is my HTML code:

   ```html
   <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">{{house.name | uppercase}}</h5>
       <p class="card-text card-text2">{{house.words | uppercase}}</p>

       <p  name="houseUrl" [(ngModel)]="houseUrl" #UrlForHouse="ngModel" >{{house.url | uppercase}}</p>
       <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="printHouseUrlInConsole(UrlForHouse.value)">Print URL In Console</a>
   </div>
   ```
4. and then the method in component:

   ```ts
   public houseUrl:string;
   public printHouseUrlInConsole(url:string):any {
   console.log(url);
   }
   ```

   Now unfortunately it is returning a null value in console log 
   and an error:  `No value accessor for form control with name: 'houseUrl'`.

   I don't know how to pass, I just saw that we need to use `ngModel` and that's why I did so, I do not know how to implement `ngModel`.
5. Also I don't want to show the URL to public I just want its value and send it to component by `ngModel`, so how to achieve all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[ngModel]` is used with the forms API. It is designed to be used on form elements like `<input>` or `<select>`. You do not need it on the `<p`>.

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{house.name | uppercase}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text card-text2">{{house.words | uppercase}}</p>

    <p  name="houseUrl">{{house.url | uppercase}}</p>
    <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="printHouseUrlInConsole(house.url)">
       Print URL In Console
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks fro the help, My bad.But in some cases I need to send some value on button clicks, is there any way to do that, say for example I need to increase count on button click how to do that? That is why I was interested in ngModel

Comment: @Tomasz Kula: where is the ``input`` in your answer ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI I think you are asking me, there is no input.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ngModel` with `p` tag. that's why you are getting:

`No value accessor for form control with name: 'houseUrl'`

Try:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{house?.name | uppercase}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text card-text2">{{house?.words | uppercase}}</p>

    <input  name="houseUrl" [(ngModel)]="houseUrl" (change)="printHouseUrlInConsole($event.target.value)" />{{house?.url | uppercase}}
    <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="printHouseUrlInConsole(houseUrl)">Print URL In Console</a>
</div>
```

**Live Demo:** go to console and click on `Print URL In Console`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-demo-kmsitm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks for the effort, I'm going for interpolation at this moment, but I know I will be needing ngModel in future . So can you direct me to a education source which handles all these topics effectively, because it is better to know than to waste time in hacking a solution.